# If I "use" a BinaryWriter, do I also need to call Close? - F#

Tags: f#

I understand that if I am working with a BinaryWriter, and I declare it with "use" instead of "let," it will automatically call the "Dispose" method when I am done with it. Does this Dispose also call "Close" on the BinaryWriter, or do I need to call Close as well, to ensure that the underlying streams are also closed?

```
use byteWriter = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream(bytes))
[1;2;3] |> List.iter(fun s -> byteWriter.Write(int16(s)))
byteWriter.Close()   // is this needed?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.close.aspx) for `BinaryWriter.Close` states:

> This implementation of Close calls the Dispose method passing a true
>   value.

so no it should not be needed since `Dispose` will be called when exiting the scope of the `use`.

If you look at the [source for BinaryWriter](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/binarywriter.cs,92) you can see that `Close` and `Dispose` both just call `Dispose(true)`.